Automated bad segment detection in EEGLAB
I am new to EEG pre-processing. I wanted to know if there is any way to detect bad segments in the EEG data automatically in EEGLAB? I found resources for automated detection of bad channels and arifact detection and rejection using ICLabel. However, i do not find any for bad segment detection and rejection. I have a lot of data and manually detecting it will be very time consuming. I heard about AMICA. But it seems to do ICA decomposition and I am satified with runica. If I am not wrong, AMICA doesnt detect bad segments.
Looking forward to your insights.
I tried AMICA as was recommended by someone, that doesnt seem to work to detect and mark bad segments. I did it manually for some participants, but it is not a feasible option for so many participants and long data sets
